# Function won't work if called outside

Tags: javascript

Function doesn't work and I get undefined if I call console.log(window.Test) outside of the function..

Works when I call inside the function in this code below--

```
var num = 0;
function clientseed() {

var a = "test";
num++;

window.Test = a + "-" + num;

console.log(window.Test)
}
```

But not with the one below --- even though im using window. which is for defining global variable but I get undefined result.. if I click the button 3 times and go to console and enter console.log(window.Test) it shows undefined also

```
var num = 0;
function clientseed() {

var a = "test";
num++;

window.Test = a + "-" + num;

}

console.log(window.Test)
```

Html

```
<button onclick="clientseed()">Test</button>
```

Comment: The function is not yet executed! If you put the `console.log` outside the function, it will get executed before the button is clicked!

Comment: thanks surajck understood.

Answer (score 1):

> even though im using window. which is for defining global variable but I get undefined result..

You are using `window`, that is fine but, even before you declaring the variable, your log statement got executed.

Case 1 (top code snippet) :

```
Button click {

 // declared the variable
 // printed.

}
```

Case 2 :

```
Button click {

 // declared the variable

}

// printed.  -- well the button not yet clicked. I don't know what is the variable you are asking me to print.
```

Comment: im new to javascript, totally understood now and I will change my concepts for the desired outcome.

Comment: @user7716943 We all started from there. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

`window.Test` is undefined.  You are out of scope, this means that you are defining a global variable within a function that has not yet been called.  `Test` does not exist yet.  This is why when you call `console.log(window.Test)` you get `undefined`.

Something you could do is move the `console.log` to be triggered after setting the variable `Test`

**E.g.**

```
function clientseed() {
   // window.Test gets defined 
}

console.log(window.Test); // outputs undefined because clientseed() was never executed which sets the definition for Test
```

When you click your `button`, it triggers `clientseed()` to be called.  You than go through each command within that function, towards the end you set `window.Test = a + "-" + num;`.  `NOW` the variable `Test` exist in the scope of `window`.  When `clientseed()` is called, it does not execute `console.log(window.Test)` again.  the reason be, it is out of scope of that function.  That function only `clientseed()` only cares about itself and what is worried about executing what is contained within the `{}`.

So, if you look in your `console` after clicking the `button 3 times`, you will notice `undefined` only shows up once.  This is exactly to that point above. When the page loads it will call `console.log(window.Test)`.  It won't execute `clientseed()` until you execute it.  Because of that, `Test` in `window` does not exist.

I hope this offers some clarity.

Comment: Thanks David, could you show the code example, I didn't understand what you mean by triggered

Comment: @user7716943 I've offered some more explanation.

Comment: Does it make sense?